# Cant find a way to set fps for sf::Time

Tags: c++, sfml

```
Myclass
{
void run();
sf::Clock m_clock;
float m_time;
float timestep
}
Myclass::run()
{
if (m_time>= timestep)
{
//update
m_time-=timestep;
}
restartCLock();
}
Myclass::restartCLock()
{
m_time+=m_clock.restartAsSeconds();
}
```

How do i do the same but when m_time is being sf::Time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `sf::Time` has the operators `>=`, `-=` and `+=` overloaded. You can just change the type from `float` to `sf::Time`.

```
struct Myclass
{
    void      run();
    void      restartCLock();
    sf::Clock m_clock;
    sf::Time  m_time;
    sf::Time  timestep = sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f);
};

void
Myclass::run()
{
    if (m_time >= timestep)
    {
        // update
        m_time -= timestep;
    }
    restartCLock();
}

void
Myclass::restartCLock()
{
    m_time += m_clock.restart();
}
```

Comment: I forgot to define timestep as sf::Time thus i was getting errors. By the way why do i need to restart clock that way? It doesnt seem to make sense for me. Why cant just m_time= m_clock.restart()?

Comment: The function `restart` resets the clock to zero and returns the time elapsed since the last restart. Everytime you call `restartClock` you add that time to `m_time` which contains the time since the beginning. When enough time as passed (`m_time >= timestep`) you update your game.